# Dirichlet energy given Dirichlet boundary condition

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, reference-request, harmonic-functions

Let $\Omega = B(0,1) \subset \mathbb R^n$. Given $f \in C(\partial \Omega)$ (though I guess what I want to do may make more sense in some other space of functions), we can solve the Dirichlet problem for $u_f$ with boundary condition $f$:
$$
\Delta u_f(x) = 0, x\in\Omega, 
$$
$$
u_f(s) = f(s), s \in \partial\Omega
$$
which has a unique solution.

Then we can consider the Dirichlet energy of $u$
$$
I(f) := I[u_f] = \int_{\Omega} \vert \nabla u_f \vert^2.
$$
Using this procedure we have a map from the space of boundary conditions to $\mathbb R$.

This map is clearly not linear but it satisfies
$$
I(f+g) = \int_{\Omega} \vert \nabla u_{f+g} \vert^2
= \int_{\Omega} \vert \nabla u_f + \nabla u_g \vert^2 \leq 2 I(f) + 2I(g).
$$
The natural way to study this map is (probably) using the representation of solutions using the Poisson kernel but I haven't had much success.
Also, by using the divergence theorem, we have that $2\int_\Omega \vert \nabla u \vert^2 = \int_\Omega \Delta(u^2) = \int_{\partial\Omega} \nabla(u^2) \cdot \nu = 2\int_{\partial\Omega} f \nabla u \cdot \nu$.

I have several questions about this map

- Is this map continuous? I guess it depends on the space of boundary conditions I choose so which one is the natural candidate?
- Can I control from below and above this quantity using some norm? Clearly, $L^p$ norms are not enough since constant functions $f$ have $I(f) = 0$.
- Does anyone have some reference on something similar to this?

Comment: Now I notice that the Dirichlet energy is the scalar product on $\partial\Omega$ of the compatible Dirichlet and Neumann boundary conditions. Unfortunately, I have no idea how we can go from one to the other